# Are there any online courses/resources to help you start making Electronic Music with a PC/Mac?

Tags: learning, electronic-music

So, I know nothing about music and would like to accelerate my learning. Are there any online courses/resources to help you go from zero to Electronic Music guru?

Paid or free.

Comment: Google is free. It also contains more knowledge than was available in an entire university course when I was first learning. *Caveat - It also contains more uneducated opinion, but the Beatles didn't go to college*

Comment: But with Google, the information is scattered, and I don't know which is the best. I.e. the info isn't curated...

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with sound design.

Answer (score 1):

Lynda.com has a lot of information from a design and production perspective, but honestly, a great way to get started is to find a YouTube channel. I don't have a specific one to recommend, but I would check out a few a see is they're making the kind of sound you like.

There are a lot of great tutorials on using Ableton live for example.

Answer (score 1):

Groove3.com has a wealth of tutorials on production, software, recording, mixing and so forth.  You can purchase tutorials as a package ala carte or pay for a monthly subscription and have unlimited access to all of their content.  I've used their resources in the past and while the ala carte price is a bit high the quality of their videos is some of the best.  I would recommend the monthly subscription as if you've got the time it is the best bang for your buck.

YouTube has a tremendous number of people with channels devoted to learning.  I really hate to give suggestions for specific channels and overlook other talented people but one of the more popular channels as of late is put together by a guy who goes by Sadowick.  Some other great resources would be Tom Cosm or Mr. Bill. For clarification, I am not Mr. Bill despite my user name.